# Magento, change getSku() to other field

Tags: magento

So i am trying to modify a plugin in order to meet my needs for Magento.

I have the following code:

```
<?php foreach($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
    sa('ecommerce', 'addItem', JSON.stringify({
        'order_id': '<?php echo $_order->getData($this->getTransactionIdField()) ?>',
        'product_id': '<?php echo $_item->getSku() ?>',
        'name': '<?php echo str_replace('\'','', $_item->getName()) ?>',
        'price': '<?php echo number_format($_item->getPriceInclTax(), 2) ?>',
        'quantity': '<?php echo (int) $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>'
    }));
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

and i want to change the product_id to a custom field. I tried changing it to:

```
'product_id': '<?php echo $_item->getData('barcode') ?>',
```

without any luck. barcode is an attribute setted in the products, different than sku. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the product attribute `barcode` by loading product from order item like :

`$_item->getProduct()->getBarcode()`

So the complete code will be like :

```
<?php foreach($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
sa('ecommerce', 'addItem', JSON.stringify({
    'order_id': '<?php echo $_order->getData($this->getTransactionIdField()) ?>',
    'product_id': '<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->getBarcode() ?>',
    'name': '<?php echo str_replace('\'','', $_item->getName()) ?>',
    'price': '<?php echo number_format($_item->getPriceInclTax(), 2) ?>',
    'quantity': '<?php echo (int) $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>'
}));
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_item` from `$_order->getAllVisibleItems()` returns `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`, not `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`

You have 2 options:

1. load original product and retrieve custom attribute from there:
   `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId())->getData('barcode');`
2. pass product attribute to order item: [product attribute to quote item and order item](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/product-attribute-to-quote-item-and-order-item/3810#3810)